# Read header/ column values from json using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint

I have this json, I want to fetch only the headers name, like [ID,Pname,Psales]

```
object {1} 
 d {1} 
  results [4] 
   0 {6} 
     __metadata {3} 
        Id : 1 
        Pname : bike 
        Psales : 9898
```

Have tried using below code,   but it displays only "d".

```
var keys = Object.keys(jsonData);
alert(keys);
```

can any one suggest how can I do this?

Comment: You have something like { d: {...} } and you're accessing the keys of json in the wrong level of your data structure.

Comment: because your `jsonData` has only 1 key, what is `d`.  try `alert(jsonData.d.results);`

Comment: Try  try alert(Object.keys(jsonData.d.results[0].__metadata))

Comment: ok, will try now and revert

Comment: No, it didn't worked. it says ' Object.keys: argument is not an Object'

Comment: @lolka_bolka : if I use jsonData.d.results , it gives [0,1,2,3] , i.e, number of my results .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing data in wrong level. Try this

```
alert(Object.keys(jsonData.d.results[0].__metadata))
```